# ctags alternatives for fortran90/95

Tags: ctags, fortran90, fortran95

I have used `ctags` for `FORTRAN 90/95` but I am looking for something better, something that can tell me all references of a tag.

I just used understand for fortran and liked it but its too expensive. I have a large  code written by someone else.

Comment: You might be interested in Photran -- http://www.eclipse.org/photran/

Comment: it appears understand for fortran is very good.

Comment: Yes, I liked Understand too when I tried it.  I regularly try to get my manager to buy me a copy, so far without success :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could try codeblocks - there is a fortran attachment written by http://darmar.vgtu.lt/.  Has syntax highlighting and function searches etc.  Not as good as the MS Visual Studio/IVF combination but still usable.